# Segmentation fault and returning the value stored in an element?

Tags: c++

Header

```
#ifndef INTVECTOR_H
#define INTVECTOR_H

using namespace std;
class IntVector{
private:
    unsigned sz;
    unsigned cap;
    int *data;
public:
    IntVector();
    IntVector(unsigned size);
    IntVector(unsigned size, int value);
    unsigned size() const;
    unsigned capacity() const;
    bool empty() const;
    const int & at (unsigned index) const;
};

#endif
```

Main

```
#include "IntVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> iVector;
int *array;
IntVector::IntVector(){
    sz = 0;
    cap = 0;
    *data = NULL;
    vector<int> iVector (sz);
    iVector.reserve(sz);
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size){
    sz = size;
    iVector.resize(sz);
    iVector.reserve(sz);
    cap = iVector.capacity();
    array = new int[sz];
    array = 0;
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size, int value){
    sz = size;
    iVector.reserve(sz);
    cap = iVector.capacity();
    array = new int[sz];
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        array[i] = value;
    }
}

unsigned IntVector::size() const{
    return sz;
}

unsigned IntVector::capacity() const{
    return cap;
}

bool IntVector::empty() const{
    if(sz > 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

const int &IntVector::at(unsigned index) const{
    if(index > sz){
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

I'm having this pesky problem of trying to set int *data to NULL as I get a segmentation error.  What method should I be using to assign *data to Null in IntVector to avoid the segmentation fault?  It doesn't look like that I am reassigning anything to *Data so I am a bit confused.

The second part of my question is the function IntVector::at.  It is supposed to return the value stored in the element at the passed in index position but I am not sure how I can return the value directly as it is a dynamically allocated array and what I've read on Google was pretty confusing.  Do I have to use a special parameter to access the value?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a bit off-topic, but `exit(0);` for an invalid index? How is anyone supposed to figure out what's wrong? You might consider throwing an exception. And what's going on with `array` and `iVector`? They aren't part of your class and using them like they are is going to screw you over really badly.

Comment: For my assignment, I have to dynamically allocate an array like for IntVector(unsigned size)  "Sets both the size and capacity of the IntVector to the value of the parameter passed in and dynamically allocates an array of that size as well."

Comment: Yes, that's what `data` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*data = NULL;
```

You're not setting `data` to `NULL` (prefer `nullptr`), you're setting *the value at* `*data` to `NULL`.  `data` is an uninitialized pointer here, so dereferencing it is invalid.

What you wanted was:

```
data = NULL;
```

Or, better

```
data = nullptr;
```

Or, best, use an initializer list.

```
IntVector::IntVector() : sz(0), cap(0), data(nullptr)
{
    // I removed your vector initialization since 
    // you're just using sz, which has a value of 0.
    // iVector is already initialized here, but I don't
    // believe that you mean to shadow it as you are doing.
    // iVector is declared statically, and then again here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*data = NULL;
```

sets the contents of the memory location to NULL. But since data does not yet point anywhere, this is not valid.